# Inheritance PHP Class

Tags: php, class, inheritance

Is there a way to inherit a class and set all methods to protected or private?

I reffer to C++ inheritance type:

```
class A {
   public: void Hello(){ /* prints a hello world */ }
};

class B : protected A {
};
```

In this case, the *public* methods would inherit as **protected**.

If I change protected to *private*, the *public* and *protected* methods would inherit as **private**.

My question is: Is it possible to do that in **PHP**?

Comment: No, it's not possible in `php`.

Comment: Nope, you can't specify an inheritance access modifier in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not use inheritance access modifiers in PHP (PHP does not have the functionality).

The general concept of Access modifier is newly incorporated in PHP with `PHP 5`. `PHP 4` does not have access modifiers. Access modifiers in PHP, is used more likely for decorating classes, so that the class composition, look like more object oriented in style. In C++, access modifiers make sense, where they are enforceable. In scripting languages like php, they can easily be ripped out by using reflection.